# Can I reask a story-identification that never got (correctly) answered?

Tags: support

I asked [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91098/looking-for-a-book-about-a-genetically-engineered-person) question, over 4 years ago but despite the attempts of several people couldn't get the correct book found.

Is it okay to reask the question in order to try to get other people to have an attempt at it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you should never reask a question just because it wasn’t answered correctly. There is already a feature in place for this case and that is to place a bounty on said question. Place a bounty, pick the appropriate reason and you should gain a lot of extra attention. Not only does it bump the question to the homepage but it also adds it to the Featured tab which makes it more visible as a whole.

Comment: ah you are correct. For some reason I thought I couldn't add a bounty twice on the same question. I guess you can though. thank you

Comment: @Aequitas One of the answers on your question doesn't have any comment from you. It might be worth adding a comment just to say that isn't what you're looking for. Maybe some people saw an answer with no "that isn't it" comment and just assumed the question was solved.

Comment: Also, of course, stating why a particular answer isn't correct can help provide additional details that hadn't occurred to you when you first asked the question. "No, it's not *Manacles of Fate*. I know that there was no subplot about the magical properties of red herrings, and the protagonist wasn't Welsh."